# Is there anyway to stop charging when laptop battery is < 80%?

Tags: linux, battery, power, battery-life

I'm a Linux (Debian) user. I work on my laptop full days. Most of the time I forget to remove the laptop charging plug. I'm looking for something when my laptop battery is more than 80% it will disconnect from charging and when less than 20% charging should start automatically.

I found something called "TLP - Optimize Linux Laptop Battery Life". But it's not working properly for me. Laptop Model: HP Pavilion 15 AU

Comment: TLP's goal is to reduce power draw, not prolong battery's lifetime. Charging isn't controlled by the OS.

Comment: Are you sure your hardware doesn't do this automatically? The "unplug laptop when full" requirement is so far removed from real-world usage, that I very much hope, that this is done automatically internally. After all, it is nowadays a standard feature of all phones, since the batteries would die quickly otherwise. (Sadly, I have never figured out a way to be sure about any of this...). Battery life degradation on my 2018 laptop indicates that it is *not* done automatically though, but with laptops it is hard to tell, whether the battery is damaged or the software too wasteful.

Comment: ***Some*** laptops support power charge limiting and there is [some evidence that it is supported in their gaming laptops](https://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Gaming-Notebooks/Setting-a-battery-charge-limit-80-on-HP-Pavilion-laptop/td-p/7495989) but not necessarily all units have this level of firmware control over the charging the hardware, or if they have it they may not actually bother to expose it beyond their rather limited "intelligent battery care" modes. Particularly in units where the batteries are trivially replaceable they may not consider it a necessary feature.